# How to fix bootstrap dropdown menu problem

Tags: html, css

I am practicing using Twitter Bootstrap. I've repeatedly tried to implement a dropdown menu, but I can't seem to make it work. Can anyone please help me identify why the HTML shown below is not resulting in a working Bootstrap dropdown menu?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" style="padding: 20px;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12" style="height: 50px; padding: 0px;   margin: 0px;">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">

                            Academic
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">academic 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">academic 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">academic 1</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    <li><a href="">Result</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Notice Board</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2" style="height: 800px; border: 1px solid;">

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-7" style="height: 800px; border: 1px solid;"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-3" style="height: 800px; border: 1px solid;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12" style="height: 150px; border: 1px solid;">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need JQuery

Comment: first you might want to put the script tag in the head tag and specify the script type. second check that from your file all script path are good

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks everyone i got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing jquery CDN

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

That may be the problem, unless it works fine.

```html
<html>
    <head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" style="padding: 20px;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12" style="height: 50px; padding: 0px;   margin: 0px;">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">

                            Academic
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">academic 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">academic 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">academic 1</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    <li><a href="">Result</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Notice Board</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2" style="height: 800px; border: 1px solid;">

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-7" style="height: 800px; border: 1px solid;"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-3" style="height: 800px; border: 1px solid;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12" style="height: 150px; border: 1px solid;">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

</b>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should mention  instead of

Use the following. Hope it will work now.

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
<span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
<li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: no, its not but tnx for your answer. in my code i didn't connect jquery.